# Open Atom editor from git shell

Tags: git, text-editor, atom-editor

i am using a win 8-X64 machine, with a 1.8 GHZ processor core i5, i have both the atom editor and git bash installed on this machine, is there any process by which i can start atom text editor from the Git bash shell or vice versa.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to edit a file in atom by opening it through git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to associate atom with all git operations, run: 
`git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"`

If you just want to edit files, add an alias in git:
`git config --global alias.edit "! atom"`
and now you can edit any file by calling: `git edit [filename]`

Comment: i tried to use the second command for editing a few files but i get an error from the bash shell in git it says "Expansion of alias 'edit' failed, 'atom' is not a git command.

Answer (score 3):

Add atom.exe file location in Your Environmental variables.

Follow These steps:

step 1. Right click on Your atom icon where you usually open atom editor and click Properties

step 2. Copy Start in directory

it looks like this

```
start in:  C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.7.0
```

step 5. Go to Control panel and follow this directory  `Control Panel\System and Security\System`

step 6. ON left side You will see **Advanced System Settings** click on it

step 7. then go to **Environment Variables** Tab

step 8. Inside System Variables search **Path** click on it, then click **Edit**

step 9. Add `;` at the end of all directory and Paste atom directory and click

**OK**

step 10.  Then open atom in your git bash or any console by Typing `$ start atom`

> OR

simply Type `PATH=%PATH%; C:/your atom directory` in your console and Hit Enter

Comment: I think there is also an automatic path setup for "C:\Users\PhilippeWeier\AppData\Local\atom\bin" in the last versions of atom.