# Opening an html file in windows 7 using git bash

Tags: html, git, github, windows-7-x64, git-bash

I'm trying to repeat the steps from [this video](https://youtu.be/1u2qu-EmIRc?t=11m31s).

I find that the git bash, in my Windows 7 (x64), doesn't accept the command `atom`  for opening an html file. I created the html file using the `touch` command:

I tried so many sites on **how to open a file of a text editor from git bash**, but nothing works.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! I see your post doesn't show what the error is. You say "doesn't accept the command 'atom.'" That's fine, but include the actual error. Also include the code you created the file with; you say "created using the touch command." but what was the actual command? Also include some of the things you tried and the outcomes. See [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to make your question more readable. I typically spend at least 30 minutes on a post so that I can include the right amount of detail, otherwise people won't spend time helping. Good Luck!

Comment: `atom` isnt' a command. It's the name of a Javascript-based editor that is *not* part part of bash or Linux for that matter. It has to be installed separatelly

Comment: BTW Windows 7 is no longer supported and Windows 10 includes [an entire Linux subsystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) that can run not just bash scripts, it can run any user-space binary. The Ubuntu, SUSE, Debian, Kali distros are available straigh through the Windows App store. Those aren't emulations, they are the actual user-space binaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some things to try:

1. Add the path to atom.exe to your environment variables
2. Associate atom with all git operations, run:  git config --global core.editor "atom --wait" (when you use git bash to edit, this tells it to always use atom)
3. Add an alias in git: `git config --global alias.edit "! atom"` and now you can edit any file by calling: `git edit [filename]`

Here is another SO post with something very similar (I think) to your question: [Open Atom editor from git shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274344/open-atom-editor-from-git-shell).

However, it's difficult to know what your problem is without more detail.

Comment: I tried them, but always, there is an error message that shows up:  _atom: command not found_

Comment: OK, that probably means `atom` is not added to your environmental path - or you may just need to restart to get it to take effect. Check out this post to make sure you're adding it to your environmental path correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37291770/1152809